# Resources folder in Mono for Android library

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add Activities, Fragments, Strings, etc. to a Mono for Android library.  I found a post from August 2011 [here](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Resources-from-a-Library-Project-td4657828.html) where it doesn't look possible.  However, I was hoping someone had found a work around.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add Activities and Fragments to the library, however you still cannot add Resources like Strings or Drawables.

Comment: jpobst - Any idea when we'll be able to include resources in library projects?

Comment: You can use the resources as "Embedded Resources" until the implement this (see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4459#c3).